# Javascript file not found / ERR_ABORTED

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine

I'm creating a javascript file that interacts with Trello API but when I run the file this is what it says in Chrome dev tools:

`GET http://localhost:8080/js/trello.js net::ERR_ABORTED`

`GET http://localhost:8080/js/trello.js 404 (Not Found)`

trello.js is definitely in /js and I've tried just /trello.js but nothing seems to be working. Can anyone please help a newbie? I am using Google App Engine with Python and webapp2.

HTML

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Admin Page</title>
 </head>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://api.trello.com/1/client.js?key={APIKey}"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/trello.js"></script>
 <body>
  {% if admin %}
  <p>All Work Requests</p>
  <a href="{{ logout_url }}">log out</a><br>
  <a href="trello.js">Trello test</a>
{% for result in results %}
  <table>
   <tr>
    <th><b>{{ result.email }}</th>
    <th><b> {{ result.date }}</th>
    <th><b> {{ result.title }}</th>
    <th><b> {{ result.key.id() }}</th>
    <th><a href="/delete/{{ result.key.id() }}">Delete</a></th>
    <th><a href="/assign/{{ result.key.id() }}">Assign</a></th>
   </tr>
  </table>
{% endfor %}
<p>{{ result }}</p>
  {% else %}
  <p>Welcome please <a href="{{ login_url }}">login...</a>
    <p>Not admin</p>
  {% endif %}
 </body>
</html>
```

trello.js

```
var authenticationSuccess = function() {
  console.log('Successful authentication');
};

var authenticationFailure = function() {
  console.log('Failed authentication');
};

window.Trello.authorize({
  type: 'popup',
  name: 'Getting Started Application',
  scope: {
    read: 'true',
    write: 'true' },
  expiration: 'never',
  success: authenticationSuccess,
  error: authenticationFailure
});

var myList = 'removed';

var creationSuccess = function (data) {
  console.log('Card created successfully.');
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
};

var newCard = {
  name: 'New Test Card',
  desc: 'This is the description of our new card.',
  // Place this card at the top of our list
  idList: myList,
  pos: 'top'
};

window.Trello.post('/cards/', newCard, creationSuccess);

//window.Trello.put('/cards/[ID]', {name: 'New Test Card'});
```

Comment: A quick guess: `Trello.js` vs. `trello.js`?

Comment: No unfortunately, I will edit my post to say trello.js

Comment: Ok would have been to easy :D

Comment: Idk Google app engine but I assume there is some public folder? Your js folder should be inside of it. If there is no public folder or it's already there i fear we need to wait for the experts.

Comment: You might be right about that, I'll have a read. Thanks.

Comment: Np. If you use Flask this looks promising. just put your js folder inside the `./static` folder: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/serving-static-files

Answer (score 1):

You need a static url handler in `app.yaml`.  Try:

```
- url: /static
  static_dir: foldername/static
```

`foldername` is needed if the static directory is inside a folder, where folder is at the same level as `app.yaml`.  If `static` is at same level as `app.yaml`, then it's

```
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
```

Then, put your `/js` dir inside the static dir, and change the path to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/trello.js"></script>
```

Alternatively, keep the path as you have it, and make a handler in `app.yaml` that goes straight to it:

```
- url: /js
  static_dir: somefolder/static/js
  # or static_dir: static/js if inside static dir which is at same level as app.yaml
  # or static_dir: js  if js dir at same level as app.yaml
```

I prefer to put all static files inside a `static` dir.  Like `static/js`, `static/img`, `static/fonts`, etc.  The top solutions handle all with a single `static` url handler